# Understanding Conjugate Gradient Optimization methods

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

As a beginner in ML, I find it hard to understand how **Conjugate Gradient Optimization** methods work. The sources I've looked up online have a very complicated explanation.

Can someone explain in a simple way the gist of Conjugate Gradient methods? In short, I want to know how these methods iterate & improve upon the parameter values. I understand the working of Gradient Descent very well & it would be helpful if the logic behind CG is explained in comparison to GD.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to understand is the fact that given an equation to solve $Ax=b$ and using the fact that $A$ is positive-definite and symmetric one can derive an inner product space from $A$ (one can generalize for other matrices).

That is, $\left<u,v\right>_A = u^TAv$. Then if this inner product is zero for certain vectors $u,v$ then we can say these are orthogonal (with respect to the inner product derived from $A$).

Orthogonality is an important property to have, since then the **orthogonal vectors can be used to span the set of solutions** and thus a solution $x_*$ of $Ax_*=b$ can be **expanded in terms of these vectors** which then become easy to compute (directly or iteratively).

That is:

Assume we have a set of orthogonal (conjugate) vectors $p_k$ which span the set of solutions, ie $\{p_0,p_1,..,p_{n-1}\}$, where $\left<p_i,p_j\right>_A=0$ for $i \ne j$.

$$x_*=\sum _{i}\alpha _{i}p_i \Rightarrow A x_*=\sum _{i}\alpha_i A p_i$$

Left-multiplying by $p_k^T$ yields

$$p_k^T b =p_k^T A x_*=\sum _{i} \alpha_i p_k^T A p_i=\sum _{i} \alpha_i \left\langle p_k,p_i\right\rangle_{A}=\alpha_k\left\langle p_k, p_k\right\rangle_{A}$$

and so

$$\alpha_k={\frac {\langle p_k,b \rangle }{\langle p_k,p_k\rangle_{A}}}$$

and we have our solution in terms of this expansion.

The above can also be approximated iteratively as:

1. Choose initial guess $x_0$ (without loss of generality $x_0=0$), compute first vector $p_0=b-Ax_0$, the other conjugate vectors must necessarily be orthogonal to this one (eg use orthogonalization algorithm).
2. Let $r_k = b-Ax_k$ be the residual at the kth step. Then using orthogonalization we can compute the kth vector at the kth step as $p_k=r_k-\sum_{i<k}{\frac {p_i^T A r_k}{p_i^T A p_i}} p_i$. Update $x_{k+1}=x_{k}+\alpha_k p_k$, $\alpha_k=\frac{\left<p_k,r_k\right>}{\left<p_k,p_k\right>_A}$
3. Finally after $n$ (size of $A$) steps we have $x_*=\sum _{i}\alpha _{i}p_i$ for $p_i$ and $\alpha_i$ as above.

The trick here is that we can, by definition, use the orthogonalization algorithm to derive the vectors one by one at a certain iteration step.

One advantage of this method is its fast convergence relative to gradient descent for example (theoretically it can converge in at most $n$ steps, where $n$ is the size of $A$).

On the other hand, a gradient descent method for solving $Ax=b$ would proceed as follows:

1. Choose initial guess $x_0$ (without loss of generality $x_0=0$).
2. At kth step update $x_k = x_{k-1} + \lambda \Delta_k$ (where $\Delta_k=b-Ax_{k-1}$ is the estimation of the gradient at kth step)
3. Repeat until convergence.

References:

1. [Conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method)
2. [Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#Solution_of_a_linear_system)